# Apache + php gd, caching images paradigm

Tags: php, apache, caching, text, gd

please read this carefully, hope you can help me with my paradigm ;)

**Basic version, works like mint - - -**

**I have a php+gd script that generates an image from a given text**, like so:

*[img src="renderImage.php?text=John Doe" alt="Jonn Doe" /]*

The output is an image that dispays **pre-formated** text on it. Let´s say 12px arial #000000

Then i add apache mod_rewrite to the equation, so that server try to access a cached image, and whether it wouldn´t existed, generate it through php script to get it generated (and saved as **¨John.png¨**):

*[img src="/images/cached/John Doe 2" alt="John Doe 2" /]* <- this could be virtually transformed to -> *[img src="renderImage.php?text=John Doe" alt="Jonn Doe" /]*

**Now, the advanced version - - -**

The issue comes with two things:

1.-Modifiying the php script with a more customizable api:

*[img src="renderImage.php?text=John Doe&size=36&font=verdana&color=FFFFFF" alt="Jonn Doe" /]*

2.-As we are saving the images with an excerpt of their ´text´ placeholder (e.g. renderImage.php?text=John Doe as John.png), when we get images with similar ´text´ placeholders we can get similar file names e.g.:

*[img src="renderImage.php?text=John Doe&size=36&font=verdana&color=FFFFFF" alt="Jonn Doe" /]*

*[img src="renderImage.php?text=John Doe was here !size=24&font=tahoma&color=333333" alt="Jonn Doe" /]*

**Both will save as John.png !**

****Finally, the paradigm - - - ****

How do i fix this? i have come down to one solution: Saving the images in php, with specific encrypted-like names, as:

*Pepe pecas|31/12/2010|9:57|72/arial/FFFFFF.png*

or

*Pepe pecas|31122010|9:57|72arialFFFFFF.png*

And then access them in markup as:

*[img src="/images/cached/JohnDoe_24arial333333.png" alt="John Doe" /]*

Which will be tranformed by apache making use of mod_rewrite regex to:

*[img src="renderImage.php?text=John Doe&size=24&font=arial&color=333333" alt="Jonn Doe" /]*

**WHAT DO YOU THINK?**

Answer (score 2):

Why not do an MD5 hash of the whole query string and name the image that. This would be a fairly easy way to see if that combination exists.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to waste a heck of a lot of disk space cacheing images if you allow utterly arbitrary combinations. What's to stop a malicious user from cycling through all 4 billion possible color codes, font sizes 1-200, and however many font faces? That "one" image will end up having 800+ billion images on your drive.

Especially if this is a public-facing page. It'd be trivial to write a spider to hit all possible combinations. At minimal bandwidth cost to the user, they'd exhaust your disk space and keep your CPU pegged generating useless images.

Comment: Well, i though on that as well, but not being a php programmer, i just wanted to blindly think there would be a way to fix that security issue. But now that think on it again, isn´t there a way to avoid that? if not, this automatic text-to-image script would be dangerous from start. Currently the script is publicly availabe, but it is not intended for public usage, but rather as an internal designer tool. Hiding it could be a solution? don´t now how to do it by the way.

Comment: It's not really a problem doing dynamic images - it's storing them. What's the intended usage of these images? A per-user icon/logo? If that's the case, store ONE image keyed off the user's internal ID and store the parameters used elsewhere.

Comment: Just because it's "cache" doesn't mean it has to store everything ever generated. As long as there is a reasonable algorithm for what to keep and what to remove when the allotted space is full, it doesn't need to exhaust disk space.

Answer (score -1):

@Marc B, i´ll intend to use it to generate headers [h1][/h1]

@niggles, well this could work, i´d also add the text properties to the hash calculation to make texts more unique.

**And what about hidding the script from users´ direct execution?**

Comment: @bmb, i wouldn´t say i want to cache images for saving hard disk space, but rather for not wasting cpu resources...